# Too many re-renders by a react component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

*This is a bit of a personal request.*

I am making a Card Game using React. I added a backend Express.js server, and an API, for the point system, and now I am trying to replace it, by shifting it's logic to the frontend (client) code itself.

But I am facing an issue, the `Card` component is throwing a `Too many re-renders` error. Earlier, when I was accessing my API, I fixed this by adding a `stop` hook. Which pretty much worked like this;

```
axios.post("/", object).then(() => setStop(true));
```

But now, I have no Idea how to fix it.

Someone please help me, it's a personal request (*I am making this as a gift for someone*)

**Source Code** - https://purple-salmon-uy3kza3n.ws-us14.gitpod.io/?folder=vscode-remote%3A%2F%2Fsapphire-quokka-1i5clgk7.ws-us09.gitpod.io%3A443%2Fworkspace

**Note** - Check the `./client/src/components/Card.js:24` (it's causing the error I think, the error could be from anywhere else too)

Comment: There's a bit too much going on for me to fix things. But I'd suggest reading up further on useEffect as that's what you are going to want to use. I'd also suggest reading up on Context API or redux to help avoid prop-drilling.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber oh ok then, will try that. 'preciate your help :)

Comment: @ZacharyHaber, I have left the workspace, are u still able to access it now?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems I can't access the gitpod due to insufficient permissions to start up an instance.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber, So r u saying u r only able to access it when I have kept the workspace open in my account?

Comment: Yeah, seems that way unfortunately. If you put the front end part in a codesandbox with the backend code in a folder for reference, I can work from that

Comment: @ZacharyHaber, ok will do that, but how do I transfer my entire (gitpod ) code directory to codesandbox? Also, I might have another way to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235720/discussion-between-zachary-haber-and-master-coder-xd).